# Operation on passed delegates as arguments in method

Tags: c#, delegates, return

As a part of my assigment i have to write simple delegate which takes two ints and returns int which is easy

```
public delegate int Foo(int X, int Y);

    public static int mul(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
    public static int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

Foo f1 = mul;
```

but how can I write a method that takes two delegates (Foo) as arguments, and returns delegate which will be a multiplication of results from function arguments? How to call that function?

Comment: can you check answer and tell what are you looking for ??

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
public delegate int AddThanMul(int a, int b, int c, int d);

public static AddThanMul CreateAddThanMulFunction(Foo add1, Foo add2)
{
   return (a,b,c,d) => add1(a,b) * add2(c,d);       
}
```

Usage

```
 var func = CreateAddThanMulFunction(add, add);
 var result = func(1,2,3,4); //returns 21
```

Also as mentioned, you can use 'Func<>' instead of delegate. Sometimes it's may be simpler.

For example `delegate int Foo(int X, int Y)` is equal to `Func<int,int,int>`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i was looking for. I got stuck because I tried somehow make Foo as return delegate of a function you wrote.